# sendto: Permission denied error

Tags: networking

When I run ping program I get the following error:

**sendto: Permission denied** even though I had done su.

What could be the possible reason?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have changed accidentally the configurations of user and root.
Would you please try this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install aptitude && sudo aptitude purge ping && sudo aptitude install ping
```